# String value cannot assigned to a string variable in iphone?

Tags: ios4, uitextfield

In my application, I take a UITextField value and trim it and assign to a string Variable declared in an Appdelegate. It assigns to a appdelegate variable and works well, sometimes It does not assign to the appdelegate variable.(This value is used in another view,so declared in appdelegate). Plz help...

```
NSString *txtTemp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[txtName.text  stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
txtName.text=txtTemp;
[self appDelegate].customSearchQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtTemp];

NSLog(@"--appDelegate.customSearchQuery =%@",appDelegate.customSearchQuery);
```

Comment: Make sure the `appDelegate` variable gets initialized (`appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`) before you doing the above operation.

Comment: Yes... I have initialized appDelegate.

Comment: Ok.. Use `NSLog` to display the variable `appDelegate`. See if it is showing `null` at sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably a memory management problem.
NSString creates an autoreleased object. You will have to `retain` it if you want to use it outside the method you showed above. The easiest thing is to delcare as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *customSearchQuery;
```

in your Appdelegate.h. That should do the trick.

In the dealloc-method of the appdelegate, you'll need to release it - otherwise you leak the NSString; with the declaration above, you'll add

```
customSearchQuery = nil;
```